# How do I mock a react component property in jest which is instance of another class?

Tags: reactjs, testing, mocking, jestjs

I want to test a react component which has instance of a service as a property. This service's method is called by a method in the component. I want to mock the service so its implementation is not my concern. Following is excerpts of my requirement:

```
// Component
export class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }

  someService - new SomeService(arg1, arg2)

  handleClick() {
    // some transformations
    this.someService.someMethod()
  }

  render() {
    return <Button onClick={this.handleClick}>
      </Button>
  }
}

// test
describe.only('<SomeComponent/>', () => {
  it.only('should call handleClick when button is clicked', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<SomeComponent/>) // shallow render from enzyme
    const handleClick = jest.fn()
    const instance = wrapper.instance()
    instance.handleClick = handleClick
    wrapper.find(Button).simulate('click')
    expect(handleClick).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  })
})
```

But now I get the implementation details error of the services. How can I mock the service so that I can simply test the method of my Component?

Answer (score 2):

If your project is a webpack project, then https://github.com/plasticine/inject-loader is very useful. You can simply swap any dependency with a mock in just a few lines of code.

```
describe('SomeComponent', () => {
  let SomeComponent;
  let SomeServiceSpy;

  beforeEach(() => {
    SomeServiceSpy= // {a mock/spy};
    SomeComponent= require('inject-loader!./SomeComponent')({
      '../services/SomeService': {SomeServiceSpy},
    });
  });

  it('should ...', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<SomeComponent/>)

    wrapper.find(Button).simulate('click')

    expect(SomeServiceSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  });

});
```

Note: make sure you don't import the module under test (`SomeComponent`) at the top of your file. The `require` call does that part.

Comment: this looks interesting. it is already 1:30am here. i'll try in the morning and reply to you. thank you very much.

Comment: We use this all the time in our tests. You can even mock out child components, for instance to verify that a `List` component renders `Row`s, but mocking out `Row` itself.

Comment: @Pravin did you get a chance to try it?

Comment: turns out we are not using webpack for test. it was a huge hassle to change the jest setup for the work project. I am going to try it in my personal projects. but it is a very good insight. thank you.